# Django CBV return different page based on form data

Tags: django, django-views

Using CreateView, I am trying to save and return a url based on the items selected in the form. This is for a workout log site where the second form you are directed to is based on the type of workout you want, based on info entered in the first form. I would like to do this without Javascript:

```
class WorkoutLogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Workout_Log
    template_name = 'workout/workout_log_create.html'
    fields = ['date_time', 'modality', 'workout_type', 'workout_model']

    #something like this:
    def get_success_url(self):
        if workout_type = '5 rounds'
            return reverse('five-rounds-log-create')
        elif workout_type = 'Drop Reps'
            return reverse('drop-reps-log-create')
        else 
            return reverse('workout-log-menu')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(WorkoutLogCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = reverse('workout-log-create')
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `get_success_url` method, you can access the object with `self.object`.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    if self.object.workout_type = '5 rounds'
        return reverse('five-rounds-log-create')
    elif self.object.workout_type = 'Drop Reps'
        return reverse('drop-reps-log-create')
    else 
        return reverse('workout-log-menu')
```